# Transform from string array to hashmap in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

What is the most precise way to transform from this

```
["access","edit","delete"]
```

to this

```
{access:true, edit:true, update:true}
```

Currently i loop to assign each value in object but i wonder if lodash already provide function for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LODASH**

You can map it to a array of entries and then simply use `fromPairs` of `lodash`

```
_.fromPairs(input.map(k=>[k, true]))
```

```js
var input = ["access","edit","delete"];

var res = _.fromPairs(input.map(k=>[k,true]));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**ES6**

You can map your input to a key (your each input) value (true) pair of objects and assign them.

```
Object.assign( ...input.map(k=>({[k]: true})))
```

```js
var input = ["access","edit","delete"]

var res = Object.assign( ...input.map(k=>({[k]: true})));

console.log(res);
```

In case you want a `Map` object you can map your input to entries (as used in lodash example) and simply construct a new Map like

```
new Map(input.map(k=>[k, true]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). This can all be done with a simple one-liner, that doesn't require any libraries:

```js
const input = ["access","edit","delete"];

console.log(
  input.reduce((obj, key) => { obj[key] = true; return obj; }, {})
);
```

With the new [es6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you can even make this easier:

```js
const input = ["access","edit","delete"];

console.log(
  input.reduce((obj, key) => ({...obj, [key]: true}), {})
);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to import a library for something so simple, just `reduce` the array of keys into an object indexed by those keys:

```js
const input = ["access","edit","delete"];
const output = input.reduce((a, key) => Object.assign(a, {[key]: true}), {});
console.log(output);
```

Or, assigning to the property of the accumulator rather than using `Object.assign`:

```js
const input = ["access","edit","delete"];
const output = input.reduce((a, key) => {
  a[key] = true;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to use lodash (As opposed to the above vanilla javascript [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) answers), you can use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues) to accomplish this:

```js
const input = ["access","edit","delete"];

const output = _.mapValues(_.keyBy(input), () => true)

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha256-7/yoZS3548fXSRXqc/xYzjsmuW3sFKzuvOCHd06Pmps=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```